# Assign every word from a line to a variable

Tags: shell-script, awk

I am very new to shell programming.
I have a file named **quaternary_splitted.csv** on macOS. 
Every line has 4 words. I want to take every word from each line and assign it to a variable. Please suggest some kind of **awk** command in **for loop**
The value of each of those 4 variable I want to use further in my shell program.

Thanks for the help.
Few of the lines from the file:

```
Ta Cr Mo W  
Nb Cr Mo W  
Nb Ta Mo W  
Nb Ta Cr W  
Nb Ta Cr Mo
```

Comment: Why awk? I mean, awk does this automatically: `awk '{print $3}' file` will print the 3rd field. Is that what you mean, or do you want to do this in the shell?

Comment: @terdon: *grumble grumble* Please don't reinvent the `cut(1)` wheel with `awk`, it makes things harder to read, and some of us actually have to maintain our terrible shell scripts...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a `while read` loop like so:

```
while read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 trash; do
    something with "$col1"
    something with "$col2"
    something with "$col3"
    something with "$col4"
done < /path/to/quaternary_splitted.csv
```

This will read through each line of `quaternary_splitted.csv` and set the first column to `col1`, second column to `col2`, etc.

The `trash` parameter is used to catch anything that may be in your file and unwanted.
Say you had a line: `Nb Ta Cr W what is this doing here?`.  Without trash you would get:

```
col1=Nb
col2=Ta
col3=Cr
col4='W what is this doing here?`
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked.